# How to extract firstname, middle and lastame from a fullname

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

How to extract firstname, middlename and lastname from below example.

Format

> FirstName, LastName OptionalMiddleNameOrInitial

Sample data

> JAMES, BEVERLY B
>
> MARS, CLARENCE
>
> MCCOY, JANE A
>
> FERN, GAIL MAY

```
rtrim(ltrim(substring(NAME,1,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)-1))) AS LastName
ltrim(ltrim(substring(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+2, len(NAME))))  AS FirstName
```

Comment: In **`MARS, CLARENCE MCCOY, JANE A`** which is first, middle and last names?

Comment: As an aside, I have two middle names. I never mention them unless explicitly asked for, partially to prevent problems with data sets like this. One day we'll just have "name". One day...

Comment: Jane is the first name, Mccoy is the last name and A is the middle name

Comment: Multiple middle names (or name parts) are actually quite common especially in other languages (like Dutch).

Comment: What about where are is no middle name? Can that happen as well?

Comment: some have middle name and some dont. In this example only Jane, Gail and Beverly have middlename

Comment: What is the full story? Are you having to do this because this is a flat file that a partner dropped in your lap or? Is the data correctly separated at the source? If so get the source because splitting name parts is very error prone. If there is no way then use the data in the application as is (ie. do not split it).

Comment: That all said what does your code produce? Where are you stuck?

Comment: when splitting the data i m getting this error..Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: That is another example of why this type of thing is so problematic. You have at least 1 row that does not have a comma and charindex is -1.

Comment: this has been covered so many times.Point is,  normalize your data and avoid this all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find this to be quite useful.

```
create table #temp 
( 
    FULLNAME        VARCHAR(100), 
    ID              INT 
) 

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('TUCKER, KEVIN G', 1) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('SCOTT, JOHN', 2) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('ERIC, T W', 3) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('MUNICH, SMITH D', 4) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('LYOD SR, CLIVE G', 5) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('HANSEN JR, CHARLES S', 6) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('BROWN,SHERMAN', 7) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('ANDREWS III, CLARK A', 8) 
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('MAMMTAN, MARY LOU', 9) 

DECLARE  @Suffixes  TABLE( 
                          Suffix VARCHAR(5) 
                          ) 

INSERT INTO @Suffixes 
VALUES     ('I'), 
           ('II'), 
           ('III'), 
           ('IV'), 
           ('V'), 
           ('SR'), 
           ('JR'), 
           ('1st'), 
           ('2nd'), 
           ('3rd') 

SELECT T.id, 
       T.Fullname, 
       F7.*, 
       F4.[LAST Name], 
       F4.Suffix 
FROM   #temp T 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(T.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',T.FULLNAME + ',') - 1) AS cLastName,
                           LTRIM(SUBSTRING(T.FullName,CHARINDEX(',',T.FULLNAME + ',') + 1, 
                                           LEN(T.FullName))) AS cFirstName) F1 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(F1.cLastName,CHARINDEX(' ',F1.cLastName + ' ') - 1) AS LName,
                           SUBSTRING(F1.cLastName,CHARINDEX(' ',F1.cLastName + ' ') + 1, 
                                     LEN(F1.cLastName)) AS pSuffix) F2 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                             WHEN LEN(pSuffix) > 0 
                                  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                              FROM   @Suffixes S 
                                              WHERE  S.Suffix = pSuffix) THEN 'Y' 
                             ELSE 'N' 
                           END AS SuffixExists) F3 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                             WHEN F3.SuffixExists = 'Y' THEN F2.LName 
                             ELSE RTRIM(F2.LName + ' ' + F2.pSuffix) 
                           END AS [LAST Name], 
                           CASE 
                             WHEN F3.SuffixExists = 'Y' THEN F2.pSuffix 
                             ELSE '' 
                           END AS [Suffix]) F4 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(F1.cFirstName,CHARINDEX(' ',F1.cFirstName + ' ') - 1) AS FName,
                           SUBSTRING(F1.cFirstName,CHARINDEX(' ',F1.cFirstName + ' ') + 1, 
                                     LEN(F1.cFirstName)) AS MInitial) F5 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                             WHEN LEN(MInitial) = 1 THEN 'Y' 
                             ELSE 'N' 
                           END AS MIExists) F6 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                             WHEN F6.MIExists = 'Y' THEN F5.FName 
                             ELSE RTRIM(F5.FName + ' ' + F5.MInitial) 
                           END AS [FIRST Name], 
                           CASE 
                             WHEN F6.MIExists = 'Y' THEN F5.MInitial 
                             ELSE '' 
                           END AS [Middle Initial]) F7
```

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/parsing-fullname-field-to-individual/

Answer (score 1):

I figured out

```
  SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(p.name, CHARINDEX(' ', p.name) + 1, 8000)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', (SUBSTRING(p.name, CHARINDEX(' ', p.name) + 1, 8000))) - 1)as[PatientLastName]
  case 
       when LEN(LTRIM(rtrim(p.name))) - LEN(replace(ltrim(rtrim(p.name)),' ','')) = 2
       then REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(p.name))),1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(p.name))))))
       else ''end as[PatientMiddleName]
  ,Replace(LEFT(p.Name,CHARINDEX(' ',p.Name)-1),',','') as PatientFirstName
```